# Password strength not working on resetting password Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, passwords, fosuserbundle

I've added password strength to my users password.

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *  pattern="/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{7,}/",
 *  message="Uw wachtwoord moet zeven tekens of langer zijn, minimaal één getal bevatten, een hoofletter en een kleine letter. "
 * )
 */
protected $plainPassword;
```

This works fine, but if a user wants to reset its password these password strength rules does not apply.

How can I add password strength to the reset password form?

Comment: you are using fosuserbundle ?

Comment: Yes I am, it seems that it is still using the default FOSUserBundle password strength values

Comment: your talking about changing password or resseting via mail, can you give me url !

Comment: I'm talking about resetting it via email. Unfortunately I cannot send you an url.

Answer (score 2):

```
    // vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Ressources/config/validation.xml
    <property name="plainPassword">
        <constraint name="NotBlank">
            <option name="message">fos_user.password.blank</option>
            <option name="groups">
                <value>Registration</value>
                <value>ResetPassword</value>
                <value>ChangePassword</value>
            </option>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="Length">
            <option name="min">2</option>
            <option name="max">4096</option>
            <option name="minMessage">fos_user.password.short</option>
            <option name="groups">
                <value>Registration</value>
                <value>Profile</value>
                <value>ResetPassword</value>
                <value>ChangePassword</value>
            </option>
        </constraint>
    </property>
```

The upper is just copy pasted from fosuserbundle. as you can see fosuserbundle adds the group ResetPassword. try this as well so

```
/**
* @Assert\Regex(
*  pattern="/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{7,}/",
*  message="Uw wachtwoord moet zeven tekens of langer zijn, minimaal één getal bevatten, een hoofletter en een kleine letter. ",
*  groups = { "ResetPassword"}
* )
*/
protected $plainPassword;
```

**Update**

All you have to do is add the line

```
*  groups = { "ResetPassword"}
```

to the $plainPassword annotation.

Comment: I've added the code you posted in AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml

But I'm getting the following error:

[ERROR 1845] Element 'property': No matching global declaration available for the validation root. (in /sites/zioo/www/web/ - line 1, column 0)

Is this caused because I use yml? I'm not sure.

Comment: @MarcoKoopman you just need to add the validation group in your annotation

Comment: not sure what you mean with if it is caused because you use yml. the only thing you have to add  is  the annotation part *  groups = { "ResetPassword"}

Comment: if that was unclear let me know so i can clarify my answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't get where I need to add the annotations to.

Where do I need to add the validation group to?

Comment: I've added *  groups = { "ResetPassword"} to the annotation but I still get the error message I described above.

When I add constraint mapping and a class to the XML file the error disappears but the validation.xml file will be ignored.

Comment: have you removed the file AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml again?

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *  pattern="/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{7,}/",
 *  message="Uw wachtwoord moet zeven tekens of langer zijn, minimaal één getal bevatten, een hoofletter en een kleine letter. "
 * )
 */
protected $plainPassword;
```

And

```
<property name="plainPassword">
    <constraint name="NotBlank">
        <option name="message">fos_user.password.blank</option>
        <option name="groups">
            <value>Registration</value>
            <value>ResetPassword</value>
            <value>ChangePassword</value>
        </option>
    </constraint>
    <constraint name="Length">
        <option name="min">2</option>
        <option name="max">4096</option>
        <option name="minMessage">fos_user.password.short</option>
        <option name="groups">
            <value>Registration</value>
            <value>Profile</value>
            <value>ResetPassword</value>
            <value>ChangePassword</value>
        </option>
    </constraint>
</property>
```

Wil work. The error came from an validator file I made a long time ago. This validator had an error and this error was the reason why this option wasn't working.

By adding "*  groups = {"registration"}" I fixed the error.

If you counter the same error as me check your validation files for errors and fix them.